# Internal representation of custom user types in Hibernate's 2nd level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

Hibernate stores entities in a dehydrated form in its 2nd level cache. This works fine for me until custom user types enter the scene, particulary [Jadira's UserType](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) library, which I use to map Joda time types.

Persistence works fine out of the box, but [I've discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869959/ehcache-hibernate-2nd-level-cache-maxbyteslocalheap-slow/26010141#26010141) that Hibernate will put a "raw" (serialized) reference to a `LocalDate` instance into its 2nd level cache, which causes some problems, because each `LocalDate` instance keeps tons of references to internal datastructures, which should not turn up in the cache.

Is there a way to hook into Hibernate's (de-)hydration strategy to get fine grain control over which data will eventually be stored in it's 2nd level cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jadira's UserType library uses `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType` to implement its custom types. `UserType` instances are simply serialized when put into the 2nd level cache, which is a less then ideal choice for Joda time instances.

The Problem could be solved by using `org.hibernate.usertype.CompositeUserType` instead when implementing custom types, which gives you full control how entities should be (de-)hydrated when put into (or taken out of) the cache.

I filed a feature request with Jadira, but for now I'll just move forward by implementing my own custom types.