# Custom user types in Hibernate's 2nd level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching, ehcache

I use hibernate (4.3.11.Final), ehcache (2.10.1) and jadira (5.0.0.GA) for user types.
Is any way to store in cache entity with joda LocalDateTime?
E.g. implement custom user types or tune SizeOfEngine?

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
}

public class PersonRepository implements JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
  @Cacheable("PersonCache")
  Person getOne(Long id);
}
```

Ehcache config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         name="CM1"
         updateCheck="false"
         maxBytesLocalHeap="16M">

  <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

  <cache name="PersonCache" eternal="false">

</ehcache>
```

Ehcahe's SizeOfEngine warning log:

```
net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker - The configured limit of 1 000 object references was reached while attempting to calculate the size of the object graph.
```

Relative questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012103/internal-representation-of-custom-user-types-in-hibernates-2nd-level-cache/26017682#26017682) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869959/ehcache-hibernate-2nd-level-cache-maxbyteslocalheap-slow)